# Try to find the order via data

Tags: algorithm, graph, machine-learning, automation, uml

I'm working on monitoring user's action on UI controls and now what I have is the log of users' mouse click action on the specific control.

For example: What I have got is control and it's parent control's type, ClassName, AutomationId, Name and so on.

```
[('TreeControl', u'100', u'SysTreeView32', u'\u6811\u89c6\u56fe', u'\u6811\u89c6\u56fe'), ('TreeItemControl', u'', u'', u'\u5feb\u901f\u8bbf\u95ee', u'\u5feb\u901f\u8bbf\u95ee')]
[('TabItemControl', u'', u'', u'\u4e3b\u9875', u'\u4e3b\u9875')]
[('ScrollBarControl', u'VerticalScrollBar', u'LineVScrollBar', u'\u5782\u76f4\u6eda\u52a8\u6761', u'\u5782\u76f4\u6eda\u52a8\u6761'), ('ButtonControl', u'DownPageButton', u'', u'\u5411\u4e0b\u7ffb\u9875', u'\u5411\u4e0b\u7ffb\u9875')]
[('TabItemControl', u'', u'', u'\u5171\u4eab', u'\u5171\u4eab')]
[('ScrollBarControl', u'VerticalScrollBar', u'LineVScrollBar', u'\u5782\u76f4\u6eda\u52a8\u6761', u'\u5782\u76f4\u6eda\u52a8\u6761'), ('ThumbControl', u'ScrollbarThumb', u'', u'\u4f4d\u7f6e', u'\u4f4d\u7f6e')]
[('TreeControl', u'100', u'SysTreeView32', u'\u6811\u89c6\u56fe', u'\u6811\u89c6\u56fe'), ('TreeItemControl', u'', u'', u'\u684c\u9762 (\u5df2\u56fa\u5b9a)', u'\u684c\u9762 (\u5df2\u56fa\u5b9a)')]
```

[By the way, some loops may be a lack of action. For example, some Pages may not have the scrollbar control so that users won't act.]

I want to get user's possible moving orders on every loop.In this case, what I want to get is :

```
('TreeControl'->'TabItemControl'->'ScrollBarControl').
```

What algorithm should I use to solve the situation?

**Is it possible to use these moves to generate a UML activity diagram?**

Comment: This doesn't look like a SO question... You may want to read a little bit about makrov-models and maybe try a hidden markov-model.

Comment: Just to point you to some relevant article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. Can you give a bit more explanation? In particular, it's unclear how the data you show above lets  you determine the "user's possible moving orders."